# Expose ToolTip DependencyProperty on custom DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I know that I can style the column and set the tooltip that way, but I want to have a real tooltip property on the grid column.
I am having trouble exposing a tooltip property for the textblock before it is created.
This is my custom column.

```
public class DataGridTextColumn : System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextTrimmingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextTrimming", typeof (TextTrimming), typeof (DataGridTextColumn),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(TextTrimming)));

    /// <summary>
    ///     HorizontalAlignment Dependency Property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalAlignment",
            typeof (HorizontalAlignment),
            typeof (DataGridTextColumn),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HorizontalAlignment.Left, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange), ValidateHorizontalAlignmentValue);

    public DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        ElementStyle = Application.Current.Resources["DataGridTextStyle"] as Style;
        EditingElementStyle = Application.Current.Resources["DataGridEditingTextStyle"] as Style;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     TextTrimming, only works in read-only mode
    /// </summary>
    public TextTrimming TextTrimming
    {
        get { return (TextTrimming) GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     HorizontalAlignment Property.
    /// </summary>
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalAlignment
    {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment) GetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    internal static bool ValidateHorizontalAlignmentValue(object value)
    {
        var ha = (HorizontalAlignment) value;
        return (ha == HorizontalAlignment.Left
                || ha == HorizontalAlignment.Center
                || ha == HorizontalAlignment.Right
                || ha == HorizontalAlignment.Stretch);
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = (TextBlock) base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        element.TextTrimming = TextTrimming;
        element.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment;
        return element;
    }
```

The tooltip has to be attached to the textblock.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want:

```
element.ToolTip = new ToolTip { Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Da Tooltip!" } };
```

?...

Comment: Nice syntax, but the problem is that the binding of the tooltip property has not occurred and the tooltip is null. I need to set up the binding between the new element and the tooltip

Comment: Maybe I should answer this myself but this is working https://gist.github.com/Martin-Andersen/d801bde4987ef2ce1bec#file-datagridtextcolumn

Comment: Yes you can answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this myself because I think that my findings can be really helpful.
I needed a way to bind a tooltip to a DataGridTextColumn, so I reversed engineered the Binding property. This is my code for the tooltip:

```
public BindingBase ToolTip
    {
        get { return _toolTip; }
        set
        {
            if (_toolTip == value) return;
            _toolTip = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ToolTip");

        }
    }
```

And the override of GenerateElement

```
protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        var element = (TextBlock) base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        element.TextTrimming = TextTrimming;
        element.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment;
        ApplyToolTipBinding(element, FrameworkElement.ToolTipProperty);
        return element;
    }
```

The rest of the code can be found at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Martin-Andersen/d801bde4987ef2ce1bec#file-datagridtextcolumn). I have been able to remove many meters of XAML code by replacing template columns with my custom column. You can set ToolTip, TextTrimming and HorizontalAlignment directly on the DataGridTextColumn.

I Hope that you will find the code useful.